# "Cascading" a copy costructor between different classes

Tags: c++

Suppose we have the following 3 classes : backpack, inventory and items.
Such classes are define as follows :

```cpp
    #ifndef ITEM_HH
    #define ITEM_HH
    #include <iostream>

    class Item {
    public:

      Item() { std::cout << "I'm an item " << this << std::endl ; }
      Item(const Item&) { std::cout << "I'm an item duplicated " << this << std::endl ; }
      ~Item() { std::cout << "Item Destroyed " << this << std::endl ; }

     private:

    } ;
    #endif
```

```cpp
    #ifndef INVENTORY_HH
    #define INVENTORY_HH
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Item.hh"

    class Inventory {
    public:

      Inventory() { std::cout << "I'm an inventory " << this << std::endl ; }
      Inventory(const Inventory&) { std::cout << "I'm an inventory duplicated " << this << std::endl ; }
      ~Inventory() { std::cout << "Inventory Destroyed " << this << std::endl ; }

     private:
    Item item;
    } ;
    #endif
```

and finally

```cpp
    #ifndef BACKPACK_HH
    #define BACKPACK_HH
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Inventory.hh"

    class Backpack {
    public:

      Backpack() { std::cout << "I'm an backpack " << this << std::endl ; }
      Backpack(const Backpack&) { std::cout << "I'm a backpack duplicated " << this << std::endl ; }
      ~Backpack() { std::cout << "Backpack Destroyed " << this << std::endl ; }

     private:
    Inventory inventory;
    } ;
    #endif
```

My question is, if I had a main.cc s.t.

```cpp
    #include "Backpack.hh"

    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        Backpack Char1;
        cout << endl;
        Backpack Char2(Char1);
        cout << endl;
        
        return 0;
    }
```

why don't the copies show as copies?
I'm not very familiarized with the terms/vocabulary of coding but i'll try my best to understand the answers! :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what output you expected and what you really received

Comment: When you write a user-defined copy constructor, don't just write a stub or a message if there are  members to copy.  Actually do the correct copying, otherwise you will introduce one of the hardest bugs to find, and that is making fake copies.  Then with the fake copy floating around, why the program silently fails or does the wrong things.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have broken you copy constructors.

For exmaple here:

```cpp
   Backpack(const Backpack&) {
      std::cout << "I'm a backpack duplicated " << this << std::endl ;
   }
```

you customized copy constructor and didn't instruct what do do with `inventory`.
So compiler assumed default constructor is desired here.

Do it like this:

```cpp
   Backpack(const Backpack& other) 
   : inventory{other.inventory}
   {
      std::cout << "I'm a backpack duplicated " << this << std::endl ;
   }
```

[Here is a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hsz3joTMf) where tool for logging object lifetime was introduced and your classes has been stripped from constructor customization, so default implementations are used.

Comment: Thanks! I was accidentally doing something similar ( only my mistake was to think I could do Inventory{other.inventory}, implicitly calling the Inventory class ). This fixed everything :)